# get count for all columns with specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below mentioned table:

```
ID    Type    Date                 Var1    Var2
A-1   SRT     2017-12-01 18:15:22  25      R28
A-2           Null                 Null    Null
A-3   Null                                 Null
A-4   SOY     2017-12-01 18:15:22          R28
```

I want to get the count of each column where its `Null` or blank.

I am using: `select count(*) from table1 where (Type is null or type='');` but it gives me count for only one column.

Require Output:

```
ID    Type    Date  Var1    Var2
0     2       2     3       2
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregatoin:

```
select sum(id is null) as id,
       sum(type is null) as type,
       sum(date is null) as date,
       sum(var1 is null) as var1,
       sum(var2 is null) as var2
from t;
```

This uses the MySQL feature that treats boolean expressions as numbers with "1" for true and "0" for false.

To handle blanks, just extend the idea:

```
select sum(id is null or id = '') as id,
       sum(type is null or type = '') as type,
       sum(date is null) as date,
       sum(var1 is null or var1 = '') as var1,
       sum(var2 is null or var1 = '') as var2
from t;
```

`date`s are not "blank" so the comparison is not really appropriate for dates (unless you want to compare to a "0" date).

If you don't want to type the name of the column an extra time, you can use `nullif()`:

```
select sum(nullif(id, '') is null) as id,
       sum(nullif(type, '') is null) as type,
       sum(date is null) as date,
       sum(nullif(var1, '') is null) as var1,
       sum(nullif(var2, '') is null) as var2
from t;
```

If "blank" implies spaces, then you can use `trim()` to remove them before making the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN id IS NULL OR id = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type IS NULL OR type = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date IS NULL OR date = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN var1 IS NULL OR var1 = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS var1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN var2 IS NULL OR var2 = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS var2
FROM Table1;
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1816e7/9

Comment: Better to use `COALESCE(col, '') = ''`

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum()` across all *expressions* or *columns*

```
select 
      sum(case when ID is null or id = '' then 1 else 0 end) as ID,
      ...
      sum(case when Var2 is null or Var2 = '' then 1 else 0 end) as Var2
from table1 t
```